# In ANGULARJS on: s.Id as s.Name for s in Players, show playerName in UI

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

**I need to show the Name instead of Id,now in UI I get Id for Player::::**

*In EditDialog.Html*

```
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll" ng-model="Rocker.PlayerId" ng-options="p.Id as p.Name for s in Players" required>
    <option value="">Select Players</option>
</select>
```

*In app.js File on particular controller :*

```
$scope.Players= [
    { Id : 1, Name : 'Player1' }
];
```

*In main.html when I bind all things to main page :*

`<td>{{Rocker.PlayerId}} </td>`
**what should I pass here to get the Player name**

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll" ng-model="Rocker.Name" ng-options="s.Name as s.Name for s in Players" required>
<option value="">Select Players</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<td>{{Rocker.Name}} </td>
```

This will give you the Name. But in case you want Id itself as the model value, then it is another case. For that you can do the following.

```
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll" ng-model="Rocker" ng-options="s as s.Name for s in Players" required>
<option value="">Select Players</option>
</select>
```

Rocker.id will give id and Rocker.Name will give name.

Comment: Yes, I need Id in model so that I can store that id in DB. and from db when I fetch I get Rocker.PlayerId as 1.I am storing Id in DB

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with filter service and little logic.

Controller logic:

```
$scope.getName=function(id){
    console.log(id);
    if(!angular.isUndefined(id)){
    var result= $filter('filter')($scope.Players, {Id:id})[0];
    return result.Name;

    }else{
    return "";
  }
```

HTML:

```
<select style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll" ng-model="Rocker.PlayerId" ng-options="s.Id as s.Name for s in Players" required>
    <option value="">Select Players</option>
</select>
 <td>Filtered out Name {{getName(Rocker.PlayerId)}}!</td>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yuKnuP7ExZw1I3kYv1jw?p=preview)

Comment: You just pass id to the controller and filter out the name of the person according to the selected id.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll" ng-model="Rocker.Name" ng-options="p.Name as p.Name for p in Players" required>
<option value="">Select Players</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `as` and bind the selected player directly

```
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll"
    ng-model="Rocker.selectedPlayer"
    ng-options="p.Name for p in Players" 
    required>
    <option value="">Select Players</option>
</select>
```

and show it as

```
<td>Selected player name {{Rocker.selectedPlayer.Name}} with id {{Rocker.selectedPlayer.Id}}</td>
```